# How to create group by function for multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, union

How to create group by function for multiple columns?

Here I'm using this query.By using Max aggregate function,I removed all the null values and got the result.

```
select Id,
MAX(Firstname) Firstname,
MAX(Mark1) Mark1,
MAX(Mark2) Mark2,
MAX(Mark3) Mark3
from
(
select Id,Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Parent
union
select Id,Null as Firstname,Mark1,Mark2,Null as Mark3 from Child 
union
select Id,Null as Firstname,Null as Mark1,Null as Mark2,Mark3 from Mark
) t
group by Id
```

So what my question is,will i able to create group by for rest of the fieldnames(firstname,mark1,mark2,mark3)?

Comment: use having clause.like HAVING MAX(Mark1) is not null and MAX(Mark2) is not null and MAX(Mark3) is not null

Comment: I think you can get your result using join , so add sample input data and the expected result data to clarify your need